# CSS style library for theming UI

Tags: css, cocoa, user-interface

I'm looking for a library I can use to parse style sheets. I would like to use it for theming UI stuff (in Cocoa). It would be nice if the interface is Objective-C, but C or C++ work too. I don't even need it to know about the UI classes, I can write that code myself. I'm not really sure where to look. I've spent some time tearing apart WebKit's source, but I'm not sure if I can extract the CSS-specific stuff.

While a CSS parsing library would be nice, I could go with another theming library as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still interested in a css-parser for objective-c take a look at [CSS.framework](https://github.com/rsms/libcss-osx) by [Rasmus Andersson](http://rsms.me/).

Comment: libcss-macos, which is the GitHub name, is interesting, but won't compile under Xcode 7. It's got some compiler directives and swizzling that make a major rewrite necessary to get it going again.